# How to manipulate check_snmp output with string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, nagios

Running this command:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp '-C' 'public' '-H' '10.1.1.1' '-l' 'haState' '-o' '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2620.1.5.6.0'
```

yields this:

```
SNMP OK - haState "active" |
```

I want to pipe this command to something that will output this:

```
SNMP OK - haState "active" | state=active
```

I think I need to somehow use awk inside of sed.

ideas?

Comment: | is an actual part of the output - it's typical for nagios plugins

Comment: What do you want to do with the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a pipe-line call to `GNU Awk` to achieve that,

```
echo 'SNMP OK - haState "active" |' | awk '{printf "%s state=%s\n",$0,gensub(/"/, "", "g",$(NF-1))}'
SNMP OK - haState "active" | state=active
```

i.e

```
<snmp-command> | awk '{printf "%s state=%s\n",$0,gensub(/"/, "", "g",$(NF-1))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the check output in a variable, extract the state through regex matching, and the use `printf` to format and print the desired output.

```
regex='haState "(.*)"$'
snmp_output=$(/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp '-C' 'public' '-H' '10.1.1.1' '-l' 'haState' '-o' '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2620.1.5.6.0')
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
  state="unknown"
  if [[ "$snmp_output" =~ $regex ]]; then
    state="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  fi
  printf "%s state=$state\n" "$snmp_output"
else
  : handle the error appropriately
fi
```

Comment: Not sure what is the overkill here.  Checking status of the check_snmp command is important as well.

Comment: Just meant, `bash regex` is really _slow_ and there are much faster ways to do this.